# The most appropriate way to return a hot, awaited task from F# to a caller in C# framework

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

It looks like if the following situation occurs often and I wonder

- What would be the most appropriate and shortest F# equivalent (e.g. no extra tasks created, has the same `SynchronizationContext` etc.)?
- Does the following have something that should be fixed or improved?

Here `DoAsync` is a member function derived from a framework class, it takes a parameter and returns a hot, awaited task to the caller that is some framework function.

In C#:

```
public async Task DoAsync(int x)
{
    if(x == 10)
    {
        await taskContext.ReturnAsync();
    }
}
```

Here `Async.Ignore` is from [here](http://stevegilham.blogspot.fi/2013/08/f-asynchrony-and-task-task-conversion.html)

In F#:

```
 member x.DoAsync(int x) =
     async {
         if x = 10
             return! Async.AwaitTask(taskContext.ReturnAsync() |> Async.Ignore)
         else
             return! Async.AwaitTask(Task.FromResult(0))
        } |> Async.StartAsTask :> Task
```

Look at Tomas' answer for a simpler way. As an added note, in F# 4.0 it looks like there's an overload for non-generic `Task` available. More details at [this Visual F# Tools PR](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/thinkb4coding/visualfsharp/contribution/7019).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Async.AwaitTask` and `Async.StartAsTask` is the way to go. Although you do not really need to return anything from the `async` if you just want to return a non-generic `Task`:

```
member x.DoAsync(x:int) =
  let work = async {
    if x = 10 then
      do! taskContext.ReturnAsync() |> Async.Ignore }
  Async.StartAsTask(work) :> Task
```

Comment: Hmm, never hurts to ask for a simpler way when it feels there's one. I also added a note for a [PR in F# 4.0 that provides a non-generic task](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/thinkb4coding/visualfsharp/contribution/7019) as it looked like being pertinent to this question.